# Ajax jQuery is not working in HostGator web hosting site

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have hosted a website in our premises and that it working perfectly. I have used Ajax and jQuery to retrieve the data. But when same has been hosted in hostgator web hosting site it is not working.

It is given an error.

> JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
>   SyntaxError
>   parsererror

web.config file and Ajax script

````xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="com.amazon.webservices.AWSECommerceService" value="https://webservices.amazon.com/onca/soap?Service=AWSECommerceService" />
  </appSettings>
  <location path="obsreports.com" allowOverride="true">
    <system.web>

      <customErrors mode="Off" />
      <httpRuntime executionTimeout="100000" maxRequestLength="2097151" />
      <securityPolicy>
        <trustLevel name="Full" />
      </securityPolicy>
      <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true">
        <assemblies>
          <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        </assemblies>
      </compilation>
      <httpModules>
        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </httpModules>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="GET" path="CaptchaImage.axd" type="MSCaptcha.CaptchaImageHandler, MSCaptcha" />
      </httpHandlers>
      <pages enableViewStateMac="False">
        <namespaces>
          <clear />
          <add namespace="System" />
          <add namespace="System.Collections" />
          <add namespace="System.Collections.Specialized" />
          <add namespace="System.Configuration" />
          <add namespace="System.Text" />
          <add namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" />
          <add namespace="System.Web" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.Caching" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.SessionState" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.Security" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.Profile" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.UI" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls" />
          <add namespace="MSCaptcha" />
        </namespaces>
      </pages>
      <authentication mode="Windows" />
      <trust level="Full" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="CAPTCHAHandler" verb="GET" path="CaptchaImage.axd" type="MSCaptcha.CaptchaImageHandler, MSCaptcha" />
    </handlers>
    <modules>
      runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"
    </modules>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="314572800" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
</configuration> ```
````

> Ajax jQuery code (using webmethod)

```js
function drawChartsalesyear() {
    var optionssalesyear = {
          title : 'Sales Trend by Month',
          titleTextStyle: {
                color: '#FF0000',
                fontSize: 24,
                bold: true
            },
            animation:{
                    duration: 1000,
                    easing: 'out',
                    startup: true
                    },
          vAxis: {title: 'Amount',titleTextStyle: {color: 'black',bold: true}},
          hAxis: {title: 'Month Year',titleTextStyle: {color: 'black',bold: true},slantedText:true, slantedTextAngle:90},
          pointsVisible: true
        };
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "salesdashboard.aspx/GetChartSalesYEARData",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r.d);
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart($("#saleschartYEAR")[0]);
            chart.draw(data, optionssalesyear);
        },
        failure: function (r) {
          //  alert(r.d);
        },
        error: function (r) {
         //   alert(r.d);
        }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Use your browser's _Network_ console to inspect the actual response data

Comment: In browser's Network console's instead of json data it is showing aspx page code.

Comment: Are you using an ASP.NET hosting plan from HostGator?